# Error : The status callback on localhost is not a valid URL

Tags: c#, web-services, callback, windows-services, localhost

I'm trying to make an application that can send sms using   twilio API

This API contains statusCallback attributes, which we can include a link that the API can send data about the delivery behavior ( if sms are received etc...)

```
public void sendSMS()
     foreach (var toNumber in TOnumbersList)
            {
             var message = MessageResource.Create(
             to: new PhoneNumber(toNumber),
             from: new PhoneNumber(fromNumber),
             body: msgBody,
             provideFeedback: true,
             statusCallback: new Uri("http://localhost:5000/"));// <---- 

              }
```

As you can notice , in the statusCallback I precised that I would like to send the information on localhost:5000/

In my solution explorer of visual studio 2015 I added a separated project and called it windows Service

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;

    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace WindowsService
    {
        static class Program
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            static void Main()
            {

                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                {
                    new Service1()

                };
             //   ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

                _httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000/"); // add prefix "http://localhost:5000/"
                _httpListener.Start(); // start server (Run application as Administrator!)
                Console.WriteLine("Server started.");
                Thread _responseThread = new Thread(ResponseThread);
                _responseThread.Start(); // start the response thread

            }
            static HttpListener _httpListener = new HttpListener();
            static void ResponseThread()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    HttpListenerContext context = _httpListener.GetContext(); // get a context
                   var a = context.Request.Url;                                        // Now, you'll find the request URL in context.Request.Url
                    byte[] _responseArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><head><title>Localhost server -- port 5000</title></head>" +
                    "<body>Welcome to the <strong>Localhost server</strong> -- <em>port 5000!</em></body></html>"); // get the bytes to response
                    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(_responseArray, 0, _responseArray.Length); // write bytes to the output stream
                    context.Response.KeepAlive = false; // set the KeepAlive bool to false
                    context.Response.Close(); // close the connection
                    Console.WriteLine("Respone given to a request.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After that , in the configuration of the solution I precised that I wanted the service to run before the windows form project as you can notice in the picture

[image]

So once I start the solution , I went on localhost:5000 and noticed that the service is running and the page is displaying a welcoming message

But , once the sendSMS() function is called (or invoked ) ( while the service is running) I'm receiving this error :

> Error : The status callback on localhost is not a valid URL

So my question is what I am doing wrong ? I would like to understand I am not very experienced with the web service techniques , did I forget to enable something? Or something related to asynchronous and synchronous issue ?

Note : In the past , (instead of using local-host ) , I have created a url using http://requestb.in/ ( which does the job of a webservice)  and I have copied the created url and there was no problem sending data on the link . But with when the link is localhost , the issue is noticed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Localhost" resolves to the  machine the code is currently running on, which is 127.0.0.1 (IPv4) and ::1 (IPv6).

If you pass localhost to a remote service like Twilio, the remote service will resolve "localhost" to 127.0.0.1/::1, which is itself. This doesn't make any sense and is why Twilio rejects the URL.

The callback URL you specify must be public and reachable from Twilios services, otherwise this won't work. I usually use a cheap or free Azure website for tests like this.

Comment: Very informative , and thank you for taking time answering me . Do you mind show me where can I find a free azure or anything free and effective so I can use for my twilio callback ?

Comment: You get free credits when signing up for Azure the first time (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/), plus you can run a few basic app services for free (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/).You can publish to these directly from Visual Studio. Another option is a Visual Studio MSDN subscription which gives you monthly credits but can be expensive (https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/)